# Batch FOR Loop Inserting a special character

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im trying to run this Batch FOR Loop:

```
FOR %%f in (C:\folder\*.dwg) do start /wait c:\”program
files"\Autodesk\”AutoCAD 2014"\acad.exe "%%f" /b c:\Script\cgatt.scr
```

But for some reason when I run it instead of outputting c:"program files", it outputs a weird specialcharacter in place of the double quote:
[image]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your first double quote in `c:\”program
files"\Autodesk\”AutoCAD 2014"\acad.exe`

It needs to be changed to a `"` like the other one is. The curved quotes are what is known as "smart quotes," which get added by some text editors automatically. Generally this can be avoided by coding batch scripts in text editors like Notepad or Notepad alternatives. There may also be an option in your text editor to turn smart quotes off. I highly recommend doing this, or else your scripts will continue to break.